# How i can know if my web site generated cookies at the users Pc or not

Tags: html, iis, cookies

We have a simple web site for our company, deployed under IIS. it contains 5 html pages with CSS, and some HTML web pages have links to other HTML pages, such as go to home page. now i want to check if my web site generated cookies at users machines or not? so can i do so? and usually does HTML web sites that do not have any login generated cookies?

**Edit:**

Using chrome development tools (F12) i have found the following:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the development tools in your favourite web browser, then load your website.

In Chrome, the cookies will appear in the 'Application Tab' of the development tools, and under 'Storage' you will see 'Cookies.' Microsoft Edge has them in 'Debugger> Cookies'

Expand that and it will show all the cookies that have been delivered by your website.

It's possible for a 'HTML only' site to be delivering cookies, especially if you have 3rd party content.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. now i open F12 tool on chrome and navigate to our web site. then under "Storage >>Cookies" i found a new entry with our web site url, but when i click on it , it was empty. I edited my question with a picture, so does my website use cookies from the picture ? i do not think so .. is this correct?

Comment: Nothing means no cookies; you have to load every page with that open.  If it's only 5 pages this approach should be fine. PS: you haven't obscured your domain name very well, as it's a known font I think people could guess it.. not that it matters much!

Comment: i navigate to every page inside my web site and nothing have been added.. so this mean i do not use cookies..

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cookies are generated on your Server Side and sent to the client.

You will have to go through your code and see whether it generates cookies.

Usually, if it's a regular HTML page, your server won't create a session for that and most likely that no cookie be sent to the client.
Otherwise, If you use .aspx pages or MVC (for example..) most likely that your server will generate Session Cookie and send it with the response to the client.

Another thing you'll have to check is whether your pages contain references to 3rd-party websites i.e includes of .css / .js files from CDNs like 
Cloudflare - these CDNs usually put their own cookie in your client's browser.

And lastly, your pages might contain `scripts` like Google Analytics which put some cookies in your client's browser.

Answer (score -1):

A HTML Page is not creating any cookies. Maybe you are mixing up Cache with Cookies? For example in PHP you have to define what shall be saved into a cookie. If you don't define any Cookie Variables, there won't be any cookies.